# chrome extension: Injecting code which references a script that I am also injecting - why it fails?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a jquery popup on any page, triggered on demand, when the user presses on my chrome extension.

I have permissions set to [ "tabs",  "http://*/*",  "https://*/*"  ]

I have a background page which tries to do the following:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

//chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "alert(document.title);" }, null);

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "demo.js"}, null);

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='demo.js'" }, null);
      });
```

If I uncomment the alert, it appears when I click on the extension icon.
But with the comment as it is it doesn't do anything.

Any thoughts why it fails?

UPDATE
I managed to get it working, by referencing a url and not a local resource(demo.js).
Now the code, that works, looks like this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://iamnotagoodartist.com/stuff/wikiframe.js'" }, null);
```

My local "demo.js" was a copy of the content from that url anyway.
I am not sure why it doesn't work when I reference the local file... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [chrome.extension.getURL](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL) to get the full path to the "demo.js" file.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { 
  code: "document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='" + 
    chrome.extension.getURL("demo.js") +"';" 
}, null);
```

BTW if you set tabId parameter to null, the script won't be injected into the background page but into [the selected tab of the current window](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! \n<br/> Do you know also how to be able to run it in iframe sites like gmail? I found the "all_frames": true reference but it's for content scripts which are always injected, while I only inject on demand.

Comment: You just have to set allFrames attribute to true in the 2nd parameter object (see the second link). Note that you will not be able to inject scripts into frames created via JavaScript.

Comment: tx a lot! i still get security warning in gmail, but it works

Comment: You can also use `chrome.runtime.getURL`, and it looks like `chrome.extension.getURL` is falling out of favor.

Comment: And you must enable this in manifest: `"web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"]` [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10529675/5739006) and [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `tab` id to `executeScript` so the scripts are getting injected into the backround page where you can't interact with them.

`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab, {file: "demo.js"}, null);`

Comment: thank you. I added
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "demo.js"}, null);
   
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='demo.js'" }, null);
 
Unfortunately, the same thing happens, nothing appears.

Comment: if i make a demo html page in which I include 
    <a href="javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='file:demo.js';})();">Test</a>

then the popup appears. I'm trying to inject that code on demand, into any web page.

Comment: awesome, thanks! (chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='"+chrome.extension.getURL("demo.js")+"'",allFrames:true })