# how to include a script "src"?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've managed to run a content-script including the next line:

```
  $('head').append('<script src="TemplateData/UnityProgress.js"></script>');
```

as you might guess, it looks for **affected-site.com/TemplateData/UnityProgress.js**

but I need to point to a local script instead, which is packaged along with my extension:

**manifest-dir/TemplateData/UnityProgress.js**

how do i write it the right way? tried to play with **file:///** prefix, but it doesn't seem to work. also the script is not mentioned in the manifest.json

please take in mind 
I'm a noob with javascript/manifest/extensions/web-programming 
and I may mess up things that seem basic/preunderstood

Comment: Just use a relative URL, so something without a scheme in front.

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527625/google-chrome-extension-script-injections

Comment: Is the js code loaded from the server or are you running a local js file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome extension: Injecting code which references a script that I am also injecting - why it fails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293465/chrome-extension-injecting-code-which-references-a-script-that-i-am-also-inject)